# Can template partial specialization narrow the argument type in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, partial-specialization

In the next program, struct template `A<int>` has a specialization `A<char>`:

```
template <int>
struct A { constexpr operator int() { return 1; } };

template <char c>
struct A<c> { constexpr operator int() { return 2; } };

int main() {
    static_assert( A<1000>{} == 1 ); //ok in Clang and GCC
    static_assert( A<1>{} == 2 ); //ok in Clang only
}
```

- Clang accepts the whole program.
- GCC accepts the specialization definition, but ignores it in `A<1>{}`.
- MSVC complains on such specialization:

```
error C2753: 'A<c>': partial specialization cannot match argument list for primary template
```

Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Ef95jv5E5

Which compiler is right here?

Comment: I don't think that this is what people meant by partial specialisation when they wrote the standard. So you get various random stuff.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The active [CWG issue 1647](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1647) mentions exactly this case of specializing an `int` non-type template parameter to a `char`.

It also mentions that the standard is currently lacking wording to handle type mismatches between non-type template parameters in primary templates and their partial specializations and that there is implementation divergence on the issue.